# WordPress database error for query INSERT INTO query

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am running wordpress 4.9.6 and I am using a mysql db and have created a plugin that pulls in via cron-job data. On my development environment everything looks fine, but when I deploy it to production I get the following error:

> WordPress database error for query INSERT INTO `wp_Market_api`
>   (`coin`, `id_Market`, `tag`, `algorithm`, `block_time`,
>   `block_reward`, `block_reward24`, `last_block`, `difficulty`,
>   `difficulty24`, `nethash`, `exchange_rate`, `exchange_rate24`,
>   `exchange_rate_vol`, `exchange_rate_curr`, `market_cap`,
>   `estimated_rewards`, `estimated_rewards24`, `btc_revenue`,
>   `btc_revenue24`, `profitability`, `profitability24`, `lagging`,
>   `timestamp`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Verge-Lyra2REv2',
>   '217', 'XVG', 'Lyra2REv2', '150', '730', '730', '2294046',
>   '17609.20111029', '13045.604429967', '504206285849', '3.86E-6',
>   '3.8173765867419E-6', '378.72320717', 'BTC', '$364,405,665.20',
>   '11.03276', '14.89208', '0.00004259', '0.00005748', '9', '13', '',
>   '2018-06-25 18:39:22', '2018-06-25 18:40:02', '2018-06-25 18:40:02')
>   made by do_action_ref_array, WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array,
>   MarketAPI->updateMarketAPI

I am creating a result object `$res` that I put then in my db:

```
$wpdb->insert("{$wpdb->prefix}market_api", $res);
```

Any suggestions what I wrong with my query? Besides the above output from my `php_error.log`, I do not have any further output.

Also when I run the query manually it is inserted correctly into the database.

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

Find below the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_Market_api` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `coin` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `id_Market` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `tag` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `algorithm` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `block_time` decimal(15,6) NOT NULL,
 `block_reward` decimal(15,6) NOT NULL,
 `block_reward24` decimal(25,18) NOT NULL,
 `last_block` decimal(20,3) NOT NULL,
 `difficulty` decimal(25,5) NOT NULL,
 `difficulty24` decimal(25,5) NOT NULL,
 `nethash` decimal(25,5) NOT NULL,
 `exchange_rate` decimal(20,11) NOT NULL,
 `exchange_rate24` decimal(25,22) NOT NULL,
 `exchange_rate_vol` decimal(27,18) NOT NULL,
 `exchange_rate_curr` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `market_cap` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `estimated_rewards` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `estimated_rewards24` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `btc_revenue` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `btc_revenue24` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `profitability` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 `profitability24` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 `lagging` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=163 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: can you share the table stucture?

Comment: @George Thank you for your reply! Please find in my updated answer the table structure.

Comment: did you declare the `global $wpdb` before insert?

Comment: @George Yes, I have declared the object in the beginning of my function, like the following `global $wpdb;`. Any other suggestion what I could check?